# Setting up a RESTful backend mock with Sinon.js for an Angular.js application

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, sinon

I'm developing an Angular.js application that has RESTful services which extend the $resource service. This app will connect to a Java Spring application in the future, but right now I'm trying to set up an isolated mock that will serve all the necessary routes for my application from **client side**. I've used Sinon.js before to create a fake client side *server* that serves my routes when I developed other apps, using other MV* frameworks, such as Backbone.js.

It appears that unlike a "standard" ajax call for fetching JSON data, as JQuery/Backbone performs, Angular uses XHR differently, and it isn't "fooled" by Sinon's attempts of hijacking the request and responding from client side.

I tried to use $httpBackend to create fake routes with ready data, instead, but it appears this service was meant to be used only for unit testing, and not for the "staging environment" which I need to set up.

This is how my Sinon setup looks like, which works on JQuery.ajax, but not on Angular $resource, or $http:

```
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith("GET", /mydata/gi, [200,
    { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    JSON.stringify({
        data: "myData"
    })
]);
server.autoRespond = true;
```

Any ideas to how this doesn't work with Angular? Or better yet, does anyone know how set such mocks for Angular apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ["e2e" (end to end) $httpBackend mock](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend) is exactly what you are looking for.

Quoting the docs: 
"For fake HTTP backend implementation suitable for end-to-end testing or backend-less development please see [e2e $httpBackend mock](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend)."

"As opposed to unit-testing, in an end-to-end testing scenario or in scenario when an application is being developed with the real backend api replaced with a mock, it is often desirable for certain category of requests to bypass the mock and issue a real http request (e.g. to fetch templates or static files from the webserver)."

I also found a [good article](http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/05/27/easy-stubbing-out-http-in-angularjs-for-backend-less-frontend-development/) describing some elegant ways to use the fake back end in Angular.

Comment: Thanks JD. But I already tried using it. Unfortunately, this mock was also supposed to run with a test runner only. It might require some tweaking to make this work without a test runner available, but it seemed like that would be too much of a hassle to make it happen. I ended up providing a "real" mock backend using connect middleware patched into my Yeoman setup.

Comment: I take that back, it seems that the article you found describes how to initialize the $httpBackend in a non testing environment. I still haven't tried it myself, as I have another working solution. I'll update once I get the chance to try it and see if it solves my problem as I expect it to. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks Naor, let me know what you find out.

Answer (score 2):

It's really a hassle to setup a full stub REST server using sinon.js or `$httpBackend`. I suggest you use FakeRest, a fake REST server built on top of sinon.js.

https://github.com/marmelab/FakeRest

Disclaimer: we wrote it.